# Clear terminal on start

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, java, gnome-terminal

Everytime I bring up my terminal I always see this Java usage pop up.
I didn't mind it for a while but the Obsessive Compulsive in me is starting to get irritated.
Anyway I can clear this when I start Terminal?
I use Gnome 3.18.3

[image: Screenshot Here]

Comment: Please [edit] and add the content of your `~/.bashrc`, especially everything you added and everything relating to `java`.

Comment: Or run `grep -i java ~/.bashrc` and lets see what your java is up to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to fix the erroneous invocation of `java` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Alternatively, read `man clear`.

Comment: I was about to type "Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you [edit] and expand that answer a little?" when I saw it was you: **You're showing up in the LQ Queue!  :-)**

Comment: Ad @Fabby: The system is not completely incorrect, the answer should be a bit more explained.

Comment: @Melebius The Waltinator is still asleep but will wake up in a few hours...  **;-)**